# need selenium code for below the code by using css or xpath

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="top_message_container">
    <div style="margin-left: 544.5px; top: -100px;" class="top_msg_div"> point deleted</div>
 </div>
```

help me out how to write  selenium code using java.

I tried this

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(.,'point deleted')]")); 
String ActualMsg= webElement .getText(); 
System.out.println(ActualMsg);
```

but it is showing as `empty/null`

Comment: Try once as `String ActualMsg= webElement.getAttribute("textContent"); 
System.out.println(ActualMsg);`

Comment: thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the `XPATH` you used is matching to two `WebElements`.

Try using `By.className` if `className` value is UNIUQE.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("top_msg_div"));
String ActualMsg= element.getText(); 
System.out.println(ActualMsg);
```

---

Using `XPATH` (if above approach is NOT working):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[contains(.,'point deleted')]"));
String ActualMsg= element.getText(); 
System.out.println(ActualMsg);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply , still it is showing as null

Comment: in console it is not showing anything                                             log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: It is NOT the stack trace. please share the code and how you are running the test

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way. 
`String xpath="//div[@class='top_message_container']/div";
WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
String text=wb.getText();
System.out.println(text);` And By this am able to print the value. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJrFZ.png)